# Disk Partition in Linux

Tags: linux, debian, partition, disk

Hi guys I made partitions in my HDD during the installation of parrot security. The problem is that I cannot see those Partitions anywhere. They exist physically, I checked via  (sudo fdisk -l) and the output is :

[image: Output]

Is there something wrong? In my file manager it shows 3 drives

1. CD ROM
2. TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100 (My HDD)
3. File System (Here it shows 100 gb which I declared bootable)

When I try to open my HDD (toshiba MQ...) it says : `Unable To Mount File Location`  Any Idea why this is happening? Did I partition my disk wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The output from `fdisk` shows you have 4 partitions on one drive, the first one is bootable (likely where your system has been installed to) and the third one is useable as swap.

fdisk only shows the partitions, not the filesystems on those partitions. To see the filesystems use `sudo parted -l /dev/sda` or `sudo blkid -c /dev/null /dev/sda*`. If they do not have a filesystem you first need to format them with one. This can be done with the `mkfs.*` tools (warning these tools will **destroy** any data on the partitions they format). For example, to format your second drive as ext4 run the following; **only** if you are sure there is nothing on that partition already.

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda2
```

Linux, unlike windows, has a global directory tree where filesystems can be mounted. By default linux distros mount your system partition to the root of this directory tree (aka `/`, or the root filesystem). Other partitions can be mounted anywhere you want. You can see a list of mounted filesystems and where they are mounted by running `mount`. On modern distros this will show a lot of virtual filesystems, you can filter these out by running `mount | grep '^/dev'`.

To mount a filesystem to the directory tree you can run the following:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /path/to/mount/point
```

For example, to mount your second partition (assuming it has a file system on it) to /mnt/p2 (this is a typical location you that internal/manually mounted filesystems are placed; but it can be any path of your choosing) run

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/p2
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/p2
```

Now any file you write to /mnt/p2 will be written to your second partition. This will only last until you reboot, to make your system remount it at boot add the following line to `/etc/fstab` (assuming it is formated with ext4).

```
/dev/sda2               /mnt/p2           ext4            defaults    0 0
```

To test this entry you can unmount it with `unmount /mnt/p2`; if it is mounted. Then run `mount -a` to mount everything listed in `/etc/fstab`.

Traditionally internal drives are setup with way on linux as such only root is allowed to do this by default so your gui file browser cannot, but the feature that lists partitions is included for removable media, which users are allowed to mount on modern linux distros. It also gives you quick access to the root of your filesystems once mounted. It is far easier to just configure the drives to mount at boot then to allow users to mount them at will.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only created the partition, i.e. you reserved the disk space.

Now you should prepare the partitions (formatting them), e.g. with `mkfs` and `mkswap`. Only after this phase, you can mount the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Run command "lsblk". It will show your device with mount point. Try to manually mount them.

Comment: I think they said that they tried to mount it and it failed...